# An instance of a model to render into a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I render an instance of a model into a partial with the following code `<%= render @places %>`.

I created _places.html.erb. I thought I could use the following code since the render method is supposed to iterates trhough the places collection :

```
<li>
    <%= link_to place.name, place %>
</li>
```

I get this error : `undefined local variable or method 'place' for #<#<Class:0x007fc1c0a4e6b8>:0x007fc1c05050a8>`
I have to use to make it work :

```
<% @places.each do |place| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to place.name, place %>
  </li>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'places.html', :collection => @places, :as => :place %>
```

Or, if you have the partial file as singular name, you can do it like this(without the variable :as)

```
 <%= render :partial => 'place.html', :collection => @places %>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that. I get a `undefined local variable or method 'place' for #<#<Class:0x007fc1c0a4e6b8>:0x007fc1c05050a8>`

Comment: @JustinDomingue check it out the :as variable that I just edited in the main post! this should work!

Comment: @ArthurNeves Do you need this because his partial name is plural?

Comment: @ArthurNeves I put the filename in singular and used your second solution. It now works perfectly. Thanks!